# How to enable Multidex inside flutter which is added to existing android project as module

Tags: flutter, dart

I have and android project, which I added flutter on it as module,
In my original android app, multidex is enabled, but this do not help me, when running the app in debug it's working normally, but when creating a release apk or even debug apk the FlutterFragment is appearing as white, like the engine did not attach.

Things I notice, 'flutter run --release' will ask me to support multidex, and will not run, updating the minSdkVersion to 21 and enabling multidex in .android/app/build.gradle then again 'flutter run --release' works perfect, but this have no effect on the host app because it's under .android which automatically build, and ignored by the host app.

Also I tried to search for how to update minSdkVersion to 21 instead of 16, but references lead to change in the .android which have no effect.

Answer (score 10):

Hey you can do two thing

1. Update your flutter SDK version by running command
   `flutter upgrade` 
   The new version of **flutter(2.10)** multidex  support automatically.
   simply pass the **--multidex** flag to flutter build appbundle or `flutter build apk` and your app will support **multidex**.

2.In your app folder inside android `[project_folder]/app/build.gradle` and add following lines.

```
defaultConfig {
...

multiDexEnabled true
```

}

and

```
dependencies {
...

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: is 2.10 available on stable channel ? 
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS 4.15.0-142-generic,
    locale en_IN)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at /media/user/Storage/extra/flutterSdk/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (8 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

Comment: yes 2.10 now in stable channel .
you can check medium blog post of flutter 2.10 release here https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-2-10-5aafb0314b12

Comment: Thank you, My question not about the apk of flutter, but the apk of the host app which have flutter module in it.

Comment: Thx a lot Ashutosh singh . It works wonderfully!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried properly enabling multidex support this way:

*in command line run*

```
flutter run --debug
```

then, if multidex has not been properly enabled, error logs will show up as below

[image: multidex-error-log]

*when prompted to enable multidex, type y as highlighted in the image above*

your app will be rebuilt with multidex enabled.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of investigation, the reason was related to something  in the entry point, which needed to add project name, referring to this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/91841#:%7E:text=Thanks-,for,-the%20workaround%20%2391841)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).